# SessionFactory Hibernate doesn't commit Oracle database

Tags: oracle, hibernate, sessionfactory

I work with Spring MVC 3.2.6,Hibernate 4, Oracle  and weblogic 10.3.6

I want to commit in Oracle database a entity using Hibernate and JPA. In server console I don't see errors. But when I check the Oracle table, new records aren't recorded.

This is my JPA entity

```
package eusurvey.modelA.daos;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;


/**
 * The persistent class for the PREFERENCIAS database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="PREFERENCIAS")
public class Preferencia implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="PREFERENCIAS_ID")
    private long preferenciasId;

    private String nombre;

    private String valor;

    public Preferencia() {
    }

    public long getPreferenciasId() {
        return this.preferenciasId;
    }

    public void setPreferenciasId(long preferenciasId) {
        this.preferenciasId = preferenciasId;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getValor() {
        return this.valor;
    }

    public void setValor(String valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

}
```

Service class AdministrationService.java.I use  the method createPreferencia .

```
package eusurvey.services;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Resource;



import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.SQLQuery;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import eusurvey.modelA.daos.EncuestaSem;
import eusurvey.modelA.daos.Encuestado;
import eusurvey.modelA.daos.Preferencia;
import eusurvey.tools.ConversionTools;


@Service("administrationService")
public class AdministrationService {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AdministrationService.class);

    @Resource(name="sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;



    @Transactional
    public void createEncuestado(Encuestado encuestado) throws Exception {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();



        session.save(encuestado);
    }   

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void createEncuesta(EncuestaSem encuesta) throws Exception {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();


        logger.info("fecha inicio "+encuesta.getFechaInicio());
        session.save(encuesta);
        logger.info("Grabada encuesta");
    }   

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void createPreferencia(Preferencia preferencia) throws Exception {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();



        session.save(preferencia);
        logger.info("Grabada prefencia");
    }   

}
```

Java where I call to createPreferencia method is

```
administrationService.createPreferencia(preferencia);
```

Console server messages are

```
04:46 DEBUG SQL:104 - select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual
2016-07-05 14:04:46 DEBUG SequenceGenerator:128 - Sequence identifier generated: BasicHolder[java.lang.Long[1404]]
2016-07-05 14:04:46 DEBUG AbstractSaveEventListener:131 - Generated identifier: 1404, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator
2016-07-05 14:04:46 INFO  AdministrationService:60 - Grabada prefencia
2016-07-05 14:04:46 INFO  ConsultasArielService:213 - despues de commit preferencia
2016-07-05 14:04:46 DEBUG AbstractTransactionImpl:173 - committing
2016-07-05 14:04:46 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:113 - committed JDBC Connection
2016-07-05 14:04:46 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:126 - re-enabling autocommit
2016-07-05 14:04:46 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:314 - Releasing JDBC connection
2016-07-05 14:04:46 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:332 - Released JDBC connection
2016-07-05 14:04:46 DEBUG ConnectionProxyHandler:219 - HHH000163: Logical connection releasing its physical connection
2016-07-05 14:04:46 DEBUG ConnectionProxyHandler:219 - HHH000163: Logical connection releasing its physical connection
2016-07-05 14:04:46 DEBUG ConnectionProxyHandler:219 - HHH000163: Logical connection releasing its physical connection
2016-07-05 14:04:46 DEBUG ConnectionProxyHandler:219 - HHH000163: Logical connection releasing its physical connection
2016-07-05 14:04:46 INFO  EncuestaController:92 - EncuestaControler despues de grabas encuesta
```

How can I check SQL sentence?

Comment: Just enable TRACE level logging for `org.hibernate.SQL` in order to get the output SQL or enable the config setting `hibernate.show_sql=true`.  Additionally, verify that your database connection settings are correct and that you're using the same database you're inspecting in your database browsing tool.

Comment: I have already hibernate.show_sql= true. I can see others sql. But I don't see  session.save(preferencia) sql,. Does this instruction generate a SQL instruction?

Comment: It should generate a `insert` statement, yes.  I see the sequence identifier being pinged in your logs but it acts as though the current session isn't bounded by the transaction generated by `@Transactional`.  For grins, remove the `@Transactional` annotation and wrap your code inside your method with `session.getTransaction().begin(); /* do your stuff */; session.getTransaction().commit();`  If that works, it's a transaction boundary wiring problem between `SessionFactory` and your transaction management annotations.

Comment: I have to modify an old project and  it doesn't use session.getTransaction. it has defined  in hibernate-context.xml a transactionManager. Now I am at home and I don't have my project

Comment: In spring xml I don't have <tx:annotation-driven />. Could this be the error?

Comment: Yes, adding that will allow the `@Transactional` annotation to start doing what it is suppose to do I believe.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `<tx:annotation-driven/>`
You must define transactionManager like this:

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

The id must be txManager, otherwise you should define the special id for the transactionManager like this.

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTxManager" />
```

And you should change you code like this `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED,readOnly = false)`.
If you didn't define the `Propagation`, the default value is `SUPPORTS`, if there is not a transaction outside, the code would execute in transaction. So no transaction begin and no transaction commit. 
All by all, just Use `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED,readOnly = false)`